# Заполнение односвязного списка

Tags: c++

Есть структура:

```
struck tel
{
int info;
tel *next;  //указатель на след элемент списка
} *begin, t;  //begin- указатель на начало
```

Функция для формирования списка:

```
tel* dob(tel *p, int in) {  
tel *t = new list;          // Захватываем память для элемента
    t -> info = in;         // Создаём информационную часть
    t -> next = p;          // Создаём адресную часть
return t;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как нужно дописать эту функцию, чтобы она сразу же сортировала элементы по убыванию info.

Comment: А что такое `list`?

Comment: @jnhjfhjj, разве Вам не уже не рассказывали то же самое [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/216576/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно пройтись по списку в предположении, что он уже отсортирован, найти подходящее место для нового элемента так, чтобы список остался отсортированным после вставки, и, конечно, вставить элемент на найденное место.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы на вашем месте не сортировал, а добавлял в то место куда необходимо.
Пробегаем список от начала до конца, сравнивая элемент добавляемый нами с каждым. Если наш больше, запоминает куда указывал указатель у list в tmp, перезаписываем его чтобы указывал на наш элемент, а добавляемому элементу ставим next на tmp.

Comment: @nanotexnik, в результате получаем сортировку (алгоритм известен под названием *сортировка вставками*).

Только вот пробегать до конца не надо. Достаточно остановиться в нужном месте, как описано в ответе @VladD.